# How to implement a GridSearchCV custom scorer that is dependent on a training feature?

Tags: loss-function

I would like to code a custom scoring function using the `make_scorer` function, where my `custom_function(y_true, y_pred)`calculates the DAILY sumproduct of `y_true` and `y_pred` and outputs, say the mean, for example. The problem is that the timestamps are made available in my `X` matrix as a feature and I cannot access index of current folder.

Does anyone have a clue how to make this possible?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to create a custom score function that calculates the loss and groups by day.

Here is a rough start:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics         import make_scorer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

def custom_loss_function(model, X, y):
    y_pred = clf.predict(X)
    y_true = y
    difference = y_pred-y_true
    group_timestamp = X[0] # Timestamp column
    score_by_day = np.array([difference[group_timestamp==i].sum() for i in np.unique(group_timestamp)]) # Groupby
    score_overall = np.mean(score_by_day)
    return score_overall

custom_scorer = make_scorer(custom_loss_function, greater_is_better=True)

GridSearchCV(model, 
            param_grid=param_grid,
            scoring=custom_scorer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this, but without `make_scorer`.

The "scoring objects" for use in hyperparameter searches in sklearn, as those produced by `make_scorer`, have signature `(estimator, X, y)`.  Compare with metrics/scores/losses, such as those used as input to `make_scorer`, which have signature `(y_true, y_pred)`.

So the solution is just to define your own "scoring object" directly, and reference the passed `X` to do the computation you want.  See [The User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#implementing-your-own-scoring-object) for some more details.